# socket.io with mongodb collection.watch() with next js app router

Tags: next.js, socket.io

I created a file named server.js in my root directory And I put the following code in it

```js
// server.js
const http = require("http");
const { Server } = require("socket.io");

const server = http.createServer();

const io = new Server(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: true,
    credentials: true,
  },
  allowEIO3: true,
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("Client connected:", socket.id);

  socket.on("message", (data) => {
    console.log("Message from client:", data);
    io.emit("message", data);
  });

  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("Client disconnected:", socket.id);
  });
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

Then I created a page and put the following code on it

```js
const Chat = () => {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
  const [currentMessage, setCurrentMessage] = useState("");
  const socket = io("http://localhost:3001", { transports: ["websocket"] }); 
  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("message", (message) => {
      setMessages((prevMessages) => [...prevMessages, message]);
    });
    return () => {
      socket.disconnect();
    };
  }, []);

  const sendMessage = () => {
    socket.emit("message", currentMessage);
    setCurrentMessage("");
  };
```

Everything works, but I also need in anther page to use mongodb collection.watch() to recive any update on a specific table, So, how to  use socket.io to listen to these updates and update the UI.

This is the API code

```js
export async function GET(req, res) {
  let changeStream;
  try {
    const db = await getMongoDb();
    const collection = db.collection("payments");
    const pipeline = [];
    changeStream = collection.watch(pipeline, {
      fullDocument: "updateLookup",
    });
    changeStream.on("change", (change) => {
      const updatedData = change.fullDocument;
      console.log("updatedData", updatedData);
      // Emit the updated data to all connected clients
     
    });
  } catch (e) {
    return NextResponse.json(
      { error: { message: e.message } },
      { status: 500 }
    );
}
```

**How can this API be integrated with socket.io?**

thank you